# Paralling piezo alarms

Tags: piezo

I have a simple question and I'm new to electronics but I don't know the answer so here goes!

I have a house alarm with a loud piezo sounder. The alarm has only one output connector.

- Is it possible to add more sounders in parallel with the existing one?
- What electronic design constraints would I need to consider?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add more sounders in parallel. Just make sure that the power supply and whatever control circuit can handle the extra load because the current drawn will be the current from one device times the number of devices you put in paralell.